# When should a subscriber failed listener rebuild the subscriber?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to understand the Pub/Sub example code for [handling errors using the high-level client library](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#handle_errors_using_the_high-level_client_library). In particular, I am trying to understand [the following if statement of the subscriber rebuild logic](https://github.com/googleapis/java-pubsub/blob/6d1c7d33b5cbd559611690da2d0f5e10451799ee/samples/snippets/src/main/java/pubsub/SubscribeWithErrorListenerExample.java#L71C19-L71C19):

```java
if (!executorProvider.getExecutor().isShutdown()) {
    subscribeWithErrorListenerExample(projectId, subscriptionId);
}
```

Why is this check necessary, and why should we only rebuild if the executor is *not* shut down? `subscribeWithErrorListenerExample` will in any case, rebuild and restart a subscriber and [recreate the `executorProvider`](https://github.com/googleapis/java-pubsub/blob/6d1c7d33b5cbd559611690da2d0f5e10451799ee/samples/snippets/src/main/java/pubsub/SubscribeWithErrorListenerExample.java#L57).

My first thought was that if we need this check, maybe it should say: "only rebuild if the executor *is* shut down" (i.e., remove the negation `!` in the if statement). Or, maybe the executor gets already shut down when the subscriber fails, in which case I am wondering why this check is needed in the first place.

Appreciate it if anyone has some thoughts or input.

Comment: Hi @Tobi, Will these 2 links help you in resolving your issue. [Link1](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/gax/latest/com.google.api.gax.core.ExecutorProvider.html) and [Link2](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-pubsub/latest/com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Subscriber.Builder#com_google_cloud_pubsub_v1_Subscriber_Builder_setExecutorProvider_com_google_api_gax_core_ExecutorProvider_).

Comment: Hey @ArpitaShrivastava, I am aware of the API. Can you please elaborate on how these links help to answer my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `executorProvider.getExecutor().isShutdown()` to determine whether or not to rebuild the subscriber does not seem like the best condition, agreed. The sample should and will be updated. It is especially unusual because calling `getExecutor()` creates a brand new executor.

The subscriber should only be recreated in the `failed()` method of `addListener` if the condition can be remedied. For example, one might check the status of the error to see if the subscription didn't exist and if not, create it:

```
  subscriber.addListener(
      new Subscriber.Listener() {
        public void failed(Subscriber.State from, Throwable failure) {
          System.out.println(failure.getStackTrace());

          if (failure instance of NotFoundException) {
            createSubscription(projectId, topicId, subscriptionId);
            subscribeWithErrorListenerExample(projectId, subscriptionId);
          }
        }
      },
      MoreExecutors.directExecutor());

  void createSubscription(String projectId, String topicId, String subscriptionId) {
    try (SubscriptionAdminClient subscriptionAdminClient = SubscriptionAdminClient.create()) {
      TopicName topicName = TopicName.of(projectId, topicId);
      SubscriptionName subscriptionName = SubscriptionName.of(projectId, subscriptionId);
      Subscription subscription =
          subscriptionAdminClient.createSubscription(
              subscriptionName, topicName, PushConfig.getDefaultInstance(), 10);
    }
```

Comment: Understood. Thanks for the clarification!